# What- or who- is Bast?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle

In the Kingkiller Chronicles, Kvothe's companion, Bast, does some pretty odd and magic stuff, like ripping a bird in half and turning it into flame. What is Bast? A demon? Or is he a sympathist (did I spell that right?)? Or something else I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[He is one of the Fae](http://kingkiller.wikia.com/wiki/Bast).

> .... Bast is later revealed to be a Fae creature under a glamoury.
>
> His true appearance is similar except for his eyes become fully blue with no sclera and his boots turn to cloven hooves. He is over 150 years old and a noble of the Faen Courts. His full title is Bastas, Son of Remmen, Prince of Twilight and the Telwyth Mael.

From [Patrick Rothfuss's blog](http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2014/03/update-faq-and-bast-with-his-shirt-off/):

[image: Image of Bast in true form]

And from *The Name of the Wind*:

> "Chronicler, I would like you to meet Bastas, son of Remmen, Prince of Twilight and the Telwyth Mael."